# Is this Trinette plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I googled, and it looks exactly like a Trinette plant. Am I correct? or is it different?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea what a Trinette is, but the plant in your photo is Schefflera arboricola variegata (may also be known as Heptapleurum) - variegated forms of this plant require higher light levels than their plain green cousins and do not get quite as tall.

http://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/umbrella-plant-schefflera

UPDATE - Apparently, 'Trinette' is one of the common names which may be applied to Schefflera arboricola. It's more frequent common name is Umbrella plant, although there are other varieties of plant which also  are known by umbrella plant. Whether you call it Fred or Johnny, its a Schefflera...

Comment: but my father said that the gardener said that this is a shade loving plant :(

Comment: the plain green leaved form is good  in shadier conditions, although its not a poor llight plant, but variegated forms of plants almost always require more light, unfortunately. It may be okay directly opposite your window (as per your earlier question with the image about light levels.)

Comment: I have placed it near the window. No direct light but bright indirect light.

Comment: That's where I've put mine - don't know how its going to do, only had it a couple of weeks, but they don't cope with lots of sun, so should be okay. You might find the variegation fades a bit, or it might revert to green, but it should still grow. I'll let you know how mine does too...

Comment: Green leaves are good or the yellow ones?

Comment: 'Variegated' assumes a plant has green leaves, and the variegated bit is referring to cream, yellow, white or any other colour from green interspersed between the green. So what we both might find is we end up with a totally green leaved plant, without the creamy/yellowy parts. But the plant will still grow and be healthy...